# Calculate Overtime Workhours and Updating the overtime to table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table columns `workhours` and `overtime`, and I would like to do a SQL or PHP query that checks if the workinghours are over 8 hours and if so it `UPDATE`s the worked overtime to overtime column.

Here's my table:

```
id   workinghours    overtime
1,   4.79,           ---
2,   8.73,           ---
3,   7.97,           ---
```

For example on the second row there is 8.73 hours of work and so it would update the 0.73 hours to the overtime column.

Comment: you probably need more details like data structure to get a more useful reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query :

```
update work set overtime= (case when working > 8 then (working - 8) else null end);
```

check 
[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa949/1)

Comment: This seems very viable way too, thanks for showing the SQL debugger/testing site.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
update mytable
    set overtime =
        case when workinghours > 8 then workinghours - 8 else 0 end
;
```

Comment: I'd probably add a `WHERE overtime IS NULL` at the end, so that overtime that has already been calculated is not re-calculated. Of course, that requires figures not to change once they are entered!

Answer (score 0):

```
update YourTable 
       set overtime=workinghours-8 
           where workinghours>8
```